# Redirect all traffic from domain without language code

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm searching for a way to redirect all traffic to the **root domain without a language code** to a fixed domain with a language code.

For example:

www.example.com  should redirect to     www.example.com/nl

www.example.com/subpage should redirect to  www.example.com/nl

www.example.com/nl = ok

www.example.com/nl/subpage = ok

etc ...

Can someone help me with this RewriteMatch?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following in your `/.htaccess` file:

```bash
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^/nl(/.*)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /nl%2 [R=302,L]
```

This will redirect as you have described - all request URIs that do not begin with `nl` language code will be redirected to include the language code.

However, I have made one assumption: that you would like to redirect `/subpage` to `/nl/subpage`, which was implied by your statement that `/nl/subpage` is 'okay'. If this is not the case, please update your question to be more specific.

If you are happy with the redirect, you may change `302` to `301` to make the redirect cached by browsers and search engines.